# Convert "Jan.2008" to date variable

Tags: r, date

How would I convert the following character variables to dates?

```
strDates <- c("Jan.2008", "Feb.2008")
str(strDates)
chr [1:2] "Jan.2008" "Feb.2008"

dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%b %Y")
str(dates)
Date[1:2], format: NA NA
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are dealing with months and not really dates you might be better off using the yearmon class located in the zoo package in which case you don't have to deal with days of the month in the first place: `as.yearmon(strDates, "%b.%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` requires a day element as well, so you can add that to the input string with `paste`:

```
full.dates <- paste("01", strDates, sep = ".")
```

Specify the template correctly, including separator tokens:

```
as.Date(full.dates, "%d.%b.%Y")
[1] "2008-01-01" "2008-02-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

To form a valid 'date', you also need a day which your data was lacking. So we add one, and we simply use an arbitrary day (here: first of the month):

```
R> strDates <- c("Jan.2008", "Feb.2008")
R> strptime(paste("01", strDates), "%d %b.%Y")
[1] "2008-01-01" "2008-02-01"
R>
```

Comment: Anyone know whether `lubridate` has any conversion function which assumes "day = 1" in the absence of a day field?