# Transforming monthly panel data into quarterly based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, data.table, transformation, panel-data

I have a panel dataset with countries, date and two columns with other data (inflation rate and payments from a specific program). What I want is to aggregate the data from monthly into quarterly data but based on different criteria: in case of payments I would like to sum the data of the 3 months in the quarters, while in case of inflation rate I would like to average the data. I have tried some methods suggested in different sites but I haven't been able to find the solution for my specific problem. The dataset looks like this:

```
Date      Country    Inflation    Payment
2021-01   Austria    3.2          120.0
2021-02   Austria    3.3          205.5
2021-03   Austria    3.8          42.5
2021-01   Belgium    4.7          87.0
2021-02   Belgium    3.8          92.0
2021-03   Belgium    5.4          116.0
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
Date      Country    Inflation    Payment
2021 Q1   Austria    3.4          368.0
2021 Q1   Belgium    4.6          295.0
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) Convert `Date` to a real date object (number-like, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9322923/3358272). (2) Convert _that_ date to a quarter, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21571703/3358272. (3) From there, this is just general "summarize by group", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions).

Comment: @r2evans close as dupe with multiple targets?

Comment: Final code, john: `quux[, Date := as.Date(paste0(Date, "-01"))][, qtr := lubridate::quarter(Date, with_year = TRUE)][, .(Inflation = mean(Inflation), Payment = sum(Payment)), by = .(Country, qtr)]`, where `quux` is a `data.table` with your starting data.

Comment: @zx8754, I'm always torn with questions that are "clearly" duplicates of multiple completely-disparate questions. Yes, it's dupes, and sometimes (though not here) it requires some creative combination of the different techniques. Thanks for initiating that, I think my first comment provides enough context to investigate the details, and my previous (code) comment the actual steps.

Comment: john, if the links and suggested code do not work for you, I think you'll need to [edit] your question and show code that includes steps from each step and show what about them is incorrect. At that point, @-ping me and we can work through the issues. Otherwise, hope this helps. Thanks!